# How do I use `std::error_category` and the other stuff that is in the system_error header?

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling, std-system-error

There are enough error handling strategies in C++ already. We have exception handling, error return codes and this `ERRNO` mess. What role does the `system_error` header play here? How do I use the features in there? To me, it just looks randomly put together. I'm using the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/system_error) site as a reference.

Comment: It's also been available for five years as [boost.system](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/system/doc/index.html)

Comment: Chris Kohlhoff (who was involved in designing `system_error`) has a series of blog posts on the subject, starting with http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `throw` and `catch` it as a normal exception. It's just a part of `std::exception` hierarchy. `std::system_error` extends `std::runtime_error` which extends `std::exception`

When should it be used? Typically it's used for converting C-style ERRNO errors to throw&catch handling with encapsulated error-code inside the object. This is heavily used by standard library itself especially in the new libraries working with OS-specific stuff, e.g. in `<thread>` library.